# Copy table from Excel to PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, shapes

I'm trying to copy and paste a table consisting of shape from an Excel Sheet into a PowerPoint slide using VBA keeping its source formatting [[image: Snapshot1]]. 
I want to write directly on the tale on the slide after paste. Everything seems to work fine except the shape was not pasted into the table [[image: Snapshot2]].

```
Sub CreatePP()
    Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppTextBox As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim iLastRowReport As Integer
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim templatePath As String

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ppapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    'Let's create a new PowerPoint
        If ppapp Is Nothing Then
            Set ppapp = New PowerPoint.Application
        End If
    'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
        If ppapp.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
           Set ppPres = ppapp.Presentations.Add
           ppPres.ApplyTemplate "C:\Users\luunt1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\themevpb.thmx"
        End If

    'Show the PowerPoint
        ppapp.Visible = True

         For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
         If sh.Name Like "E_KRI" Then
            ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
            ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Set ppSlide = ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
            ppSlide.Select


            iLastRowReport = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A1:J" & iLastRowReport).Copy
            DoEvents
            ppapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting")
            Wait 3
            With ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
              .Width = 700
              .Left = 10
              .Top = 75
              .ZOrder msoSendToBack
            End With
            Selection.Font.Size = 12
          'On Error GoTo NoFileSelected
            AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
            Set ppSlide = Nothing
            Set ppapp = Nothing
    End If
    Next   
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Are those oval shapes ones that were manually placed on the excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you have any way to solve it? Please help me

Comment: If they are manually placed, ie not linked to a cell, then the solution will not be an easy one.  You are going to need to cycle through the objects, find their locations, then determine the relative location on the powerpoint sheet to place them there

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting the range of the table and pasting, it may solve your solution to instead paste the table object itself, so:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Copy  'Assuming it is the only table on the sheet.  Adjust this code as needed for your specific case
```